# django best practice for use different project using both some models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i need to create 2 project a little related.

i need to use for both project some apps and models. and maybe the same settings. using different templates and domains.

can do you recommend me?

Comment: Django supports multiple sites. Look into this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#associating-content-with-multiple-sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how independent your projects are, there are two different solutions.

As karthikr reccomended, there is the *sites* package. If what you have in mind is really multiple projects that are very similar, but with different content and templates depending on the domain or URL, this is what you are looking for.

If what you have in mind is creating apps that you can reuse in multiple different projects, think about "reusable apps".
Python, and hence django, is inherently modular. This means that it is really easy to create and use apps, and to `import` them whenever you need them. Have a look at django's documentation on reusable apps:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/

For some useful advice on app design and re-usability, have a look at James Bennett's (old but not completely outdated) talk at DjangoCon 2008: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-S0tqpPga4